# why i get this error TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not bool

Tags: odoo, onchange, odoo-9

this my code :

```
 @api.onchange('birth_date','age','a')
@api.one
def update_ages_onchange(self):
    if self.birth_date < (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=(180))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'):
        d1 = datetime.strptime(self.birth_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        d2 = date.today()
        self.age = relativedelta(d2, d1).days
        a = relativedelta(d2, d1) 
        self.a = ' Less than' str(a.days) + ' days'
```

how to solve this error : TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not bool, in d1 = datetime.strptime(self.birth_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

Comment: This error is happening because the field is null and odoo convert null value to false just check if the field has value before you use it

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have this:

```
import datetime
# To convert `string` to `datetime` you should use
datetime.datetime.strptime(self.field_name, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
```

Thats all.

Also note that `self.birth_date` is string, so to compare two `datetime` you should use `datetime` instead of string.

This following code is correct:

```
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.birth_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
# where self.birth_date is fields.Datetime(string='Birth Date')
```